# Kendo UI Grid Foreign Key column empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have tried to follow an example to get a foreign key into a grid. I followed this example:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn

I have altered it a little bit because I want to use a `Popup Editor`.

Here is the `Grid` implementation in the `View`.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Example.Web.UI.ViewModels.ExampleItem>()
.Name("ExampleGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Label);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Type);
    columns.Bound(p => p.InputType);

    columns.ForeignKey(p => p.ParentId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["items"], "Id", "Name").Title("Parent");

    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
})
.Scrollable()
.Groupable()
.Sortable()
.Pageable(pageable => pageable
    .Refresh(true)
    .PageSizes(true)
    .ButtonCount(5))

.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.Id);
                model.Field(p => p.Id).DefaultValue(Guid.NewGuid());
                model.Field(p => p.ParentId).DefaultValue(null);
            })
    .Create(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Create", "Example"))
    .Read(read => read.Action("EditingPopup_Read", "Example"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "Example"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Destroy", "Example"))
)
)
```

Here is the `ExampeItem` Model:

```
public class ExampleItem
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Label { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Input Type")]
    public string InputType { get; set; }

    public ExampleItem Parent { get; set; }

    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Controller` I set the foreign key items like this:

```
ViewData["items"] = exampleItems; // This is a List<ExapleItem>
```

But for some reason the `Parent` column is empty when the `Grid` is loaded.

When I click on `Edit` a window pops up and shows me the Guid of the parent.

That Guid should be a drop down list of items. And the `Parent` column should show the name of the `Parent` item.

The idea of this grid is that you can add items to the grid, and when you do, you can choose any of the all ready added grid items as a parent item. Then creates an hierarchy in the `Grid` which can be sorted later on by the `Parent`.

Anyone know where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Check on folder `~\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\` is there a file name `GridForeignKey.cshtml` ?

Comment: Yehp there is indeed, I copied it from the examples which ship with KendoUI

Comment: The `Guid` should have worked.  What data type is your `ViewBag["items"]`?  You probably need to cast it to `IEnumerable<T>` instead of just `IEnumerable`.

Comment: It was of `ExapleItem`, spelled it wrong initially. I did cast it in a quite a few different ways. We made a business decision to can KenodUI and use another web tool instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trial and error I found the issue.

I changed my model to:

```
public class ProposalItem
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Label { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Input Type")]
    public string InputType { get; set; }

    public ProposalItem Parent { get; set; }

    [UIHint("GridForeignKey")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

So removed the `Guid` datatype from the `Id`. Also Decorated the `ParentId` with `[UIHint("GridForeignKey")]` which now gives me a `DropdownList` in the popup window.

It looks like there is a lack of Support for Guid's in KendoUI.

I will post another question as to why Guid's don't work.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but as per my experience, you forgot to add editor template for the foreign key column.

1. As per your code you have to add default editor templates into your project.

   - For default editor template detail please check [this](http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.in/2013/01/set-column-editable-mode-based-on_16.html) for full code/demo.
2. You can also create your own editor template.
   For ex:-

**column definition for the Product**

```
c.ForeignKey(x => x.ProductID, (List<Product>)ViewData["products"], "ID", "ProdName").EditorTemplateName("ProductIDEditor");
```

**Here is the editor template for Product, ProductIDEditor.cshtml**

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
                  .AutoBind(false)
                  .OptionLabel("Select a value...")
                  .DataTextField("ProdName")
                  .DataValueField("ID")
                  .DataSource(dataSource =>
                  {
                      dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("FilterProducts", "Home").Data("filterProducts"))
                                .ServerFiltering(true);
                  })                                   
            )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was thinking it might be something to do with editor templates. I will give that a try

Comment: I don't need to have this, Kendo already provide generic editor template for `ForeignKey` in editor template shared folder. Maybe because I had convert my project to use Kendo library with Telerik's tools.

Comment: If we add telerik RAD/kendoui controls using Telerik's tools then it will add all required files and settings into our project else we have to add it manually into our project.

Comment: I have added the EditorTemplate folder under Shared and the Template in there and it still does not work for some reason.

Comment: I have a Dropdown List when I change edit mode to incell. But when page loads all the rows have that column empty, even though it has been set in the controller to have a value.

Comment: Found the issue but still don't know why this is an issue. I changed the model id fields to int and it worked. For some reason it does not like the GUID as an Id. I might post another question regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in :

```
.DataSource(source => source.Ajax()
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(o => o.Id);
                model.Field(o => o.Id).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.Id).DefaultValue(Guid.NewGuid());

                model.Field(p => p.ParentId).DefaultValue(Guid.NewGuid());

                **model.Field("ParentId", typeof(Guid));**
            })
```

It has to do new Guid.